# Hibernate Validate ignore in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, jsf-2.2

My project can run on jboss7, it will be validate by hibernate validation but on tomcat7, it cannot be validate. I copied validation-api.jar, jboss-logging.jar in tomcat\lib path bur it still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*validation-api-X.Y.Z.jar* is only the Bean Validation API, you also need to copy *hibernate-validator-X.Y.Z.jar* and all other JARs provided in the *dist/lib/required* folder of the distribution JAR. Alternatively you can use Maven as described in the [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createproject) to add all the required JARs to your WAR.